# Multi Line Caret in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, lazarus

Lazarus has a feature called [Multi Caret](http://wiki.freepascal.org/New_IDE_features_since#Multi_Caret) which allows typing code in the Code Editor (Source Editor) on multiple lines at once.

Does Delphi have such a feature?

Comment: based on what i'm using (RAD studio Seattle) this option is not available in the IDE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Delphi IDE has no multi caret edit feature.